# How can I debug what is wrong ? Featured images stopped showing

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

not sure when this happened, but my featured images are now not showing. Instead I see "NO THUMB"

Any ideas how I can find the cause ? So far I have disabled and reenabled all plugins, to no avail.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : The images exist on the server in several sizes.
       WP_DEBUG is currently set to false.

UPDATE : After checking the error_log file, it appears that the first critical error is this :

```
[09-Sep-2013 13:48:02] WordPress database error Table './myhosting_mydb/wp_postmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired for query SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (1520) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, update_post_caches, update_postmeta_cache, update_meta_cache
```

Not sure what to do with this, however....

Comment: Do the images still exist on the server?

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I JUST had a similar error in fact. You need to fix your db first. Go into your mysql admin and do a repair on that table, then things should be ok. If you have phpmyadmin, do this:

1. Sign into phpMyAdmin
2. Click on your database name on the left
3. click on SQL in the tabs on the top
4. In the query box enter: "repair table wp_postmeta" and then click Go.

Hope this helps, it worked for me a couple of days ago.

Comment: That was the problem. I figured it out and solved just before reading your answer. Many thanks anyway. I repaired the database with a plugin called WP-DBManager . What a relief to see the site live again !